# Getting: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

I am creating a game using node js and socket IO.

I am creating players as following

```
  var player =  new playa.playa();
        player.name = info.name;
        player.picture = info.picture;
        player.email = info.email;
        player.user_id = info.user_id;
        player.socket = socket;
```

I then add the player to my array

```
      playerPool[info.user_id] = player;
```

mapped so I can then reference playerPool[user_Id] without having to iterate through the loop

i Then want to add my player to my game

```
        g.addPlayer(playerPool[info.user_id]);


        this.addPlayer = function(player)
        {
            var self = this;
            if(this.max_players > this.current_players.length)
            {
                 self.current_players[player_userid] =player;
            }
         }
```

However, I keep getting an error

```
for(var key in obj)  RangeError max call stack size exceeded
```

My question is

1. why is JavaScript looping through my keys?

if I Call

```
       player.user_id
```

it returns the user id of the player class, so I know it is a valid object.

I never asked JavaScript to iterate through the object, just re map it to the players array in the game class just as I did to my player pool. However this seems to be an issue. Did anyone incur the same problem?

Comment: How was playPool array declared?

Comment: first of all i see that current_player is an object it will not have length unless u assigned current_player=[] but if u initilize that way current_player[user_id] where user id = 50 will automatically create 50 values which will make the length as 50

Comment: @Huangism var playerPool = [];  that is not the problem. I am able to pass the player object and even extract its properties in the game class. the problem is the "player" object cannot be assigned to self.current_players  which is a class wide var this.current_players = []

Comment: @Sunand I see.. i think that is whats happening. How can I then successfully map keys to the current_players obj.

Comment: initialize current players as object i,e this.current_players ={} also maintain one more property say this.playerCount=0 and increment that in the add player function :)

Comment: I dont get the use of the this.playerCount ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax of the for loop does precisely that only, it loops through the key values of that object

so the syntax

```
for(var key in obj)
```

would give the keys of that object i.e. the properties. In order to access the object values you need to use obj[key] in this for loop.

Another way to get the values of the array that you create would be:

```
playerPool.forEach(function(player) {
   //Over here you get each player in the array
});
```

Comment: Interesting. ok But my question is why can i not set my object to another array?

Comment: self.current_players[player_userid] =player;  this always returns an empty array